# .net remote debugging visual studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, remote-debugging

I have Visual Studio 2013 in one machine and I have published the code in remote machine using ccnet. The remote machine has only the published code which can be run on IIS.

I want to remote debug this code from VS 2013 in local machine. I followed steps as in msdn, but when I attach to process, breakpoint turns hollow - with message, no symbol file loaded for this document.

I then changed the attach to option from AUtoimatic to Native 4/4.5. Then debug point became active, but when I debug, the points are not hit. Looks like it is enough if pdb files for vs 2013 are placed within app root directory itself. Not sure why am not able to debug.

Comment: Do the break points correct themselves when you place the PDB in the app directory on the remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

In VS2013 you can set the symbol file locations.
Tools --> Options --> Debugging --> Symbols --> Symbol file (.pdb) locations --> New (icon on top right)

Make sure that on the bottom part of the screen your module is allowed to load symbols automatically, either by choosing "All modules" or by choosing "Only specified modules" and then specifying your module.